# How can I connect a curve to a point by a straight line?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a curve in space, already plotted:

```
uno = ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sqrt[7]/3 * Cos[t], 1/9 + 2 Sqrt[7]/9 * Sin[t], 
   2/9 (1 + 2 Sqrt[7] Sin[t])}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Thick
 ]
```

Now, I want to connect several points on this ellipse to the origin by straight lines. I try with Table and Line but just got lines connecting the center of the ellipse and the contour. Any ideas?

Comment: Which "several points"? I don't see them anywhere in your question. Otherwise, you can just do something like `Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ points` and then display them with `Graphics3D[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't exactly specify which points you are interested in, in a first attempt I will just **extract all the points** that `ParametricPlot3D` has already calculated to plot your ellipse.

```
points = Cases[uno, Line[{pts__}] -> pts, Infinity];

Show[
 uno,
 Graphics3D[{Red, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ points}],
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Green,
   InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
   InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
   }],
 ViewPoint -> {20, 20, 10}, ViewAngle -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Alternatively, of course, you could use `Table` or similar constructs to generate some **evenly spaced points**, if that's what you are after.

```
evenlines = Table[
   Line[{
     {0, 0, 0},
     {Sqrt[7]/3*Cos[t], 1/9 + 2 Sqrt[7]/9*Sin[t], 
      2/9 (1 + 2 Sqrt[7] Sin[t])}
     }],
   {t, 0, 2 Pi - Pi/8, Pi/8}
  ];

Show[
 uno,
 Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, evenlines}],
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Green,
   InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
   InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
   }],
 ViewPoint -> {40, -60, 15}, ViewAngle -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]